# C++ Text file won't save in Unicode, it keeps saving in ANSI

Tags: c++, file, text, unicode, fwrite

So basically, I need to be able to create a text file in Unicode, but whatever I do it keeps saving in ANSI.

Here's my code:

```
    wchar_t name[] = L"‎中國哲學書電子化計劃";
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("chineseLetters.txt", "w");

    fwrite(name, sizeof(wchar_t), sizeof(name), pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
```

And here is the output of my "chineseLetters.txt":

```
     -NWòTx[øfû–P[SŠƒR  õ2123
```

Also, the application is in MBCS and cannot be changed into Unicode, because it needs to work with both Unicode and ANSI.

I'd really appreciate some help here. Thanks.

Thanks for all the quick replies! It works!

Simply adding  L"\uFFFE‎中國哲學書電子化計劃" still didn't work, the text editor still recognized it as CP1252 so I did 2 fwrite instead of one, one for the BOM and one for the characters, here's my code now:

```
    wchar_t name[] = L"‎中國哲學書電子化計劃";
    unsigned char bom[] = { 0xFF, 0xFE };
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("chineseLetters.txt", "w");
    fwrite(bom, sizeof(unsigned char), sizeof(bom), pFile);
    fwrite(name, sizeof(wchar_t), wcslen(name), pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
```

Comment: I hate to just throw you a link but to start off, you **need** to read this: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/unicode.html)

Comment: It didn't solve your problem for me but I think your `frwite()` call should be: `fwrite(name, sizeof(wchar_t), sizeof(name)/sizeof(wchar_t), pFile);`

Comment: I suspect your problem may be putting UTF-8 characters (via text editor) into fixed size (wchar_t) character string. It works fine for me if you use `char` rather than `wchar_t` (assuming my fix above).

Comment: Just once, at the beginning of your file, write two bytes: FF FE. Then write your text and see what happens.

Comment: @Galik: All the major compilers are smart enough to handle UTF-8 <-> UTF16 conversions in source code, the usual trip up is if they mix up CP-1252 <-> UTF-8.  Since he's got Chinese into a wchar_t, odds are the compiler is reading the data right.  My bet is that the output text is valid, and he's opening it in notepad, which is rendering the UTF-16 as CP-1252.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there's invisible characters before the `-`, and another between the `N` and `W`, and yet a third between the `2` and the `1` near the end.

Comment: If I'm right about the CP-1252 encoding, the raw bytes are "`0E 20 2D 4E 0B 57 C3 B2 54 78 5B C3 B8 66 C3 BB E2 80 93 50 5B 53 C5 A0 C6 92 52 20 20 C3 B5 32 10 31 32 33`".  The correct UTF-16 data ought to be "`200E 4E2D 570B 54F2 5B78 66F8 96FB 5B50 5316 8A08 5283`".  I'm baffled that the first 6 bytes match, but none after that.

Comment: The code in the question saves 40 bytes to the file, but your post only lists... actually it's 40 if I include the leading spaces...  That output makes NO SENSE AT ALL

Comment: Will keep saying over and over: People, use UTF-8 and all your problems vanish. See http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to be able to create a text file in Unicode

Unicode is not an encoding, do you mean UTF-16LE? This is the two-byte-code-unit encoding Windows x86/x64 uses for internal string storage in memory, and some Windows applications like Notepad misleadingly describe UTF-16LE as “Unicode” in their UI.

> fwrite(name, sizeof(wchar_t), sizeof(name), pFile);

You've copied the memory storage of the string directly to a file. If you compile this under Windows/MSVCRT then because the internal storage encoding is UTF-16LE, the file you have produced is encoded as UTF-16LE. If you compile this in other environments you will get different results.

> And here is the output of my "chineseLetters.txt": -NWòTx[øfû–P[SŠƒR  õ2123

That's what the UTF-16LE-encoded data would look like if you misinterpreted the file as Windows Code Page 1252 (Western European).

If you have loaded the file into a Windows application such as Notepad, it probably doesn't know that the file contains UTF-16LE-encoded data, and so defaults to reading the file using your default locale-specific (ANSI, mbcs) code page as the encoding, resulting in the above [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

When you are making a UTF-16 file you should put a Byte Order Mark character U+FEFF at the start of it to let the consumer know whether it's UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE. This also gives apps like Notepad a hint that the file contains UTF-16 at all, and not ANSI. So you would probably find that writing `L"\uFEFF‎中國哲學書電子化計劃"` would make the output file display better in Notepad.

But it's probably better to convert the `wchar_t`s into `char` bytes in a particular desired encoding stated explicitly (eg UTF-8), rather than relying on what in-memory storage format the C library happens to use. On Win32 you can do this using the [`WideCharToMultibyte` API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx), or with wide-open `ccs` as described by Mr.C64. If you choose to write a UTF-16LE file with `ccs` it will put the BOM in for you.

Comment: Note that I think he also has a problem in using the `sizeof()` on the whole string buffer length: `fwrite(name, sizeof(wchar_t), sizeof(name), pFile);`. I think the third argument should be **`_countof(name)-1`**, i.e. `wcslen(name)`.

Comment: "rather than relying on what in-memory storage format the C library happens to use]" Not sure what you mean by that.  He's using `wchar_t [21]`

Comment: `wchar_t` is not the same on all platforms.  On some, it is 16bit (useful for UTF-16), but on others it is 32bit instead (useful for UTF-32). `wchar_t` is not a portable data type. `char16_t` and `char32_t` were added in C++11 to replace it.

Comment: I don't think the  internal storage encoding is UTF-16LE here, because the author wrote that:  _Also, the application is in MBCS and cannot be changed into Unicode, because it needs to work with both Unicode and ANSI._ But I am not sure how MBCS and UTF16 are different from each other

Answer (score 3):

*"Unicode"* is a generic term, and you may want to clarify *which* kind of Unicode **encoding** you plan to use in your file.

Unicode [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a common choice (it's particularly well suited to exchange text data across different platforms, since it has no concept of *"endiannes"*, there's no little-endian/big-endian confusion unlike with UTF-16, and it's widely used across the Internet), but there are also other options (like e.g. UTF-16 on Windows, which directly maps to `wchar_t`-strings in Visual C++).

If you are using Visual C++, you can specify a **`ccs`** attribute in the second parameter of `fopen()` (or `_wfopen()`), choosing your desidered encoding, e.g. `"ccs=UTF-8"` for the UTF-8 encoding.
You can read more details about that on [the MSDN documentation of `fopen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx), e.g.:

> **`fopen`** supports Unicode file streams. To open a Unicode file, pass a `ccs` flag that specifies the desired encoding to **`fopen`**, as
>   follows.
>
> ```
> fp = fopen("newfile.txt", "rt+, ccs= encoding ");
> ```
>
> Allowed values of *encoding* are **`UNICODE`**, **`UTF-8`**, and
>   **`UTF-16LE`**.

I think with **`UNICODE`** they mean **UTF-16BE** (i.e. big-endian UTF-16); the other two options are clear.

---

**EDIT**

I tried with this code, and it works fine in saving the Chinese text using Unicode UTF-8 (I used Visual Studio 2013):

```
wchar_t name[] = L"‎中國哲學書電子化計劃";
FILE * file = fopen("C:\\TEMP\\ChineseLetters.txt", "wt, ccs=UTF-8");
...check for error...

fwrite(name, sizeof(wchar_t), _countof(name)-1, file);
fclose(file);
```

Note that, after pasting the Chinese text in the source file and saving it, the Visual Studio editor figured out it needed to save the source file in Unicode to not loose text information, and showed a dialog-box asking for confirmation.
So, **consider saving the source file in Unicode** if you have some "hard-coded" Unicode text in it (in production-quality Windows/C++ code, you may want to save text in **resource** files).

Note also that I used **`_countof()`** instead of `sizeof()` in the `fwrite()` call.
You had:

> ```
> fwrite(name, sizeof(wchar_t), sizeof(name), file);
> ```

but that is **wrong**, since you want to specify as the third argument **the count of `wchar_t`s**, not a total size in bytes (note that in MSVC, `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2`, i.e. a `wchar_t` is two `char`s, i.e. **two bytes**).

Moreover, you have to consider **`-1`** to the total buffer length in `wchar_t`s, since you don't want to write the `NUL`-terminating `wchar_t` in the Unicode string buffer.
(In case of a Unicode UTF-16 `wchar_t` string of unknown static size, you can simply use `wcslen()` to get the count of `wchar_t`s excluding the terminating `NUL`).

This is how the UTF-8 file written above is correctly opened in Word:

[image: Chinese Text From UTF-8 File Showed in MS Word]